# JWT signature failed errors are not coming as JSON errors in SLIM

Tags: php, jwt, slim-3

I am using Firebase JWT in one of my SLIM framework apps for RESTFul api. But all the JWT errors occur as slim app error rather than throwing back json errors ,which i can return to user.
Like in image below
[image]
[image: SignatureInvalidException]

Can you help how can i display JWT errros in json format ,so that my restful api return that json error to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to output error as JSON, you need to handle the exception. For example:

```
try {
    //do something when everything is OK
} catch (\Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException $e) {
    return $response->withJson(
       (object) [
          'error' => true,
          'code' => $e->getCode(),
          'message' => $e->getMessage()
       ],
       500
    );
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this like below

try {
      $decoded =  (array) JWT::decode($jwt, $invalid key, array('HS256'));
      print_r($decoded);
     }
     catch (Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException $e) 
     {
      return $response
        ->withJson($e->getCode(),500);
     }

But still i get same slim app error only :(

Comment: Maybe because it was different exception?

Comment: Slim shows below error nly
Details
Type: Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException
Message: Signature verification failed